# Cannot build blender from source on ubuntu 16.04 (Error at CMake Compile)

Tags: scripting

I'm asking the same question at https://blenderartists.org/t/cannot-build-blender-from-source-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-at-cmake-compile/1111985

## What I tried to do

I'm trying to build blender for the first time and ran into some errors during compiling. I use ubuntu 16.04.

Following the [manual](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake), I've ran:

```
mkdir /media/allosteric/Data/PF/BlenderBuild
cd /media/allosteric/Data//-git
git clone https://git.blender.org/blender.git
cd blender
git submodule update --init --recursive
git submodule foreach git checkout master
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase origin master
make update
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install git build-essential
cd ..
./blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh
cd blender
make
```

However, this raises errors. Logs are described below. (I ran `make clean;make` for the second and later runs.)

## Logs

Every time the log started with:

```
Configuring Blender in "/media/allosteric/Data/PF/BlenderBuild/build_linux" ...
-- Could NOT find Spacenav (missing:  SPACENAV_LIBRARY SPACENAV_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   regex
--   thread
--   date_time
--   locale
--   system
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Unsupported CFLAG: -Wrestrict
-- Unsupported CXXFLAG: -Wrestrict
-- Blender Skipping: (bf_alembic;bf_collada;bf_intern_ctr;bf_intern_opencl;bf_intern_utfconv;extern_sdlew)
-- Disabling Cycles tests because tests folder does not exist
```

after so, the compile halts raising errors with some varieties. The followings are some examples.

```
[ 42%] Building C object source/blender/blenkernel/CMakeFiles/bf_blenkernel.dir/intern/navmesh_conversion.c.o
[ 42%] Linking C static library ../../../lib/libbf_blenkernel.a
[ 42%] Built target bf_blenkernel
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
GNUmakefile:128: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

or

```
[ 35%] Building C object source/blender/windowmanager/CMakeFiles/bf_windowmanager.dir/intern/wm_stereo.c.o
[ 35%] Linking C static library ../../../lib/libbf_windowmanager.a
[ 35%] Built target bf_windowmanager
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
```

or

```
[ 35%] Building C object source/blender/windowmanager/CMakeFiles/bf_windowmanager.dir/intern/wm_stereo.c.o
[ 35%] Linking C static library ../../../lib/libbf_windowmanager.a
[ 35%] Built target bf_windowmanager
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
GNUmakefile:128: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and others that I haven't kept track of.

## About my PC

The OS I currently use is ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, this is a dual-boot with a Windows 10.

The `/media/allosteric/Data/PF/BlenderBuild`, which is the directory I'm currently tring to build blender, is a mount of a Data Driver originally for the Windows.

My CPU is an `Intel® Core™ i5-4210H CPU @ 2.90GHz × 4`, which is 64-bit and GPU is `GeForce GTX 950M`.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, unfortunately, due to their complex and unique nature, it was deemed too difficult to successfully answer questions about building Blender. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399/can-we-please-reconsider-allowing-qa-regarding-blender-build-problems

Comment: @RayMairlot Got it. Should I simply delete this? Or should I vote for close?

Comment: For both ubuntu 14.10 and 18.04 ("bionic beaver") I have found the install_deps script has thrown some errors.  Look into the script for options on disabling troublesome deps.  I also find cmake_gui handy to generate the makefiles.  Unfortunately my old nvidia could be of the variety that doesn't support 3.3 although its driver does,  2.8 builds Ok. but crashes at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `sudo apt install libpng16-dev` and `sudo apt install libjpeg9-dev` and blend was successfully compiled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compile the new blender 2.8, you will encounter errors compiling and/or running if your GPU didn't support >=OpenGL3.3. Other causes of errors usually occur if you have a missing library or hadn't installed them. You can see the requirements at the GitHub page or from the official download site.  Try running "blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh" after cloning the repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As for the GPU I use [GeForce GTX 950M](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-950m/specifications) which supports OpenGL4.5. As for the install._deps.sh, I already tried that several times and still didn't work.

Comment: I can see you were missing a couple of libraries